# What is async in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, keyword

I've read about new Python "keywords" `async` and `await`. However they are neither really keywords nor reserved in a namespace.

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.iskeyword("async")
False
>>> async
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'async' is not defined
```

In the example I would expect `True` and `SyntaxError` for a keyword.

So, what exactly is `async` in Python? How it works?

Comment: `async` only applies in Python 3.5. Is that the version you are using?

Comment: `async` and `await` aren't "real" keywords yet, but they will be in Python 3.7.

Comment: I use Python 3.6.0

Comment: According to [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#why-async-def-and-not-def-async) `async` is a *statement qualifier*.

Comment: @Thyrst': If you look at the [reference grammar](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/grammar.html) for Python 3.6, you'll see that `async` and `await` have no independent identity when defined without a function definition next to it. So they aren't keywords, but the compiler will recognise them if you put a lambda function next to it.

Comment: Related : [How the heck does async/await work in Python 3.5?](https://snarky.ca/how-the-heck-does-async-await-work-in-python-3-5/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For backward compatibility purposes, in Python 3.5 and 3.6, `async` and `await` are parsed through an [ugly tokenizer hack](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#transition-plan). Inside an `async def` function definition, or for an `async` directly before a `def`, the tokenizer replaces `NAME` tokens for `async` and `await` with `ASYNC` and `AWAIT` tokens; in other contexts, the tokenizer emits regular `NAME` tokens for `async` and `await`, treating them as identifiers.

You can see the code that handles it in [`Parser/tokenizer.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Parser/tokenizer.c#L1550), and you can find the backward compatibility plan in [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#transition-plan), the PEP that introduced `async` and `await` syntax.